# Using strpos to change variable content

Tags: php, string, strpos

I'm trying to remove the contents of a variable if it already exists in a string:

```
$baseurl = "http://mywebsite.ex/";
$b = $baseurl."http://";
$a = $b."http://mywebsite.ex";

if (strpos($a,$b) !== false) 
{
    echo 'true <br>';
    $baseurl = "";
    echo $a;
}
```

But when I test the script I get:

```
true 
http://mywebsite.ex/http://http://mywebsite.ex
```

I expected the result:

```
true 
http: //mywebsite.ex
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `strpos()` doesn't change variables. It only **checks** if `$a` contains `$b`. I'm not sure what are you doing in first 3 lines.

Comment: @dragoste thanks, but I do $baseurl = ""; if $a contain the $b content

Comment: your first 3 lines dont make any sense, do they? `$a` should contain something like `http://mywebsite.ex/http://http://mywebsite.ex` which doesn't make any sense, does it? so please explain what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think you have some logical problems.

**Update.** OK now I know what you wanted ;), I think **@Rizier123**: you nailed it.

What you do in you code is:

**strpos():** you are asking in this `if ( strpos( $a, $b ) !== false )` condition if `$b` ( http://mywebsite.ex/http:// ) is in `$a` ( http://mywebsite.ex/http://http://mywebsite.ex )
// this is always true because you concated the string like `$a = $b . "http.....`, so `$b` is always in `$a`

**Try this and take a look at the output:**

```
$baseurl = "http://mywebsite.ex/";
$b = $baseurl . "http://"; // b looks like http://mywebsite.ex/http://
var_dump( $b );
$a = $b . "http://mywebsite.ex"; // a looks like http://mywebsite.ex/http://http://mywebsite.ex
var_dump( $a);


// strpos: you asking in this condition if $b ( http://mywebsite.ex/http:// ) is in $a ( http://mywebsite.ex/http://http://mywebsite.ex )
// this is always true because you concated the string like $a = $b . "http....., so $b is always in $a
if ( strpos( $a, $b ) !== false ) {
    echo 'true <br>';
    $baseurl = "";
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: You're right, you fell into an error of logic, thanks to the comments I knew where was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `strpos()` you only detect if `$b` occurs somewhere in `$a`, but it doesn't remove it. To remove it you can assign the return value of `strpos()` to a variable and then cut out `$b` from `$a` with [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), e.g.

```
if (($position = strpos($a,$b)) !== false) 
{
    echo 'true <br>';
    $baseurl = "";
    $a = substr_replace($a, "", $position, strlen($b));
    echo $a;
}
```

With this you will remove the first occurence of `$b` in `$a`. And if you would want to remove all occurences, just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), e.g.

```
if (strpos($a,$b) !== false) 
{
    echo 'true <br>';
    $baseurl = "";
    $a = str_replace($b, "", $a);
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: @MirkoBrombin You're welcome. Enjoy your day :) (btw: highlighted what exactly I changed in the code and also tried to explain better what the new code does)